# Anyone know a workaround for this Chrome bug?

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-chrome, time

So I've got the following script:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<SCRIPT>
  function alert_minutes() {
    var d=new Date();
    alert ('Minutes past the hour: '+d.getMinutes());
  }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD><BODY>
  <button onclick="alert_minutes()">Click Me</DIV>
</BODY></HTML>
```

And I load it in Chrome. I press the button and it tells me

```
Minutes past the hour: 30
```

which is correct. I fast forward my local time by ten minutes, press it again and it tells me

```
Minutes past the hour: 40
```

so no problem there. Now I set my local time back to the correct time, press it a third time and it still says

```
Minutes past the hour: 40
```

I refresh the page, press it a fourth time, but it still says

```
Minutes past the hour: 40
```

I close all Chrome windows and re-open the browser and finally it knows the correct time.

So I conclude "without closing and re-opening the browser, Chrome can't handle the local time being set backwards, only forwards". This is not the case using the same script with Firefox. Anyone know a workaround for this bug? I'm using Chrome 16 on Win XP.

Comment: Who changes their computer's time in the middle of surfing? Weird edge case. lol

Comment: I would tell Google and hope getting some money from it.

Comment: That's not all: I, constantly, have to do a "clean navigation data" if I want to be sure the new changes are really in effect. I, probally, do that 1,000+ times a day. I hate it but, unfortunatelly, Chrome, for me, is the fastest browser out there and I am constantly developing ... something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's normal if chrome it is using a monotonic clock (e.g. CLOCK_MONOTONIC) to get the time

Answer (score 1):

seems to be on a five minute interval?

if you move time forward it says there for about five minutes, even if you move time back, then updates.

explain more, your reason for this function, how important is it? if the time is critical you should be doing it server side anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, also reproducable on WinXP

http://jsfiddle.net/X2HeE/2/

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function alert_minutes() {
    var d = new Date();
    alert ('Minutes past the hour: ' + d.getMinutes());
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="alert_minutes()">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

> Also I closed the 'button' tag in 9th line, you close a 'div' tag instead, but that didn't exist. The only way to reset the script, is exiting the process of the tab and then reopening it.

PS. Sorry for my English